# Difference b/w $p$ and $P(X)$ i.e. output of Binomial Distribution ($BD$)? Is it possible to have $p=1$ but $BD=0$?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I have a confusion with Binomial Distribution. For Binomial Distribution we use the formula:

$P(x) = {n \choose k} \cdot p^x \cdot (1-p)^{n-x}$

Now let's suppose $p=1$ but if we put this $1$ in $P(x)$, we will get $P(x)=0$.

How can we define this situation?

Zulfi.

Comment: While not formal I think it's thought of that if $p=1$ or $p=0$ the distribution is not really binomial any more, or at least not in the intended way you would use the distribution to model something, as there is not really two possible outcomes, success or failure, anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, funny. If $p=1$, then when you repeat the experiment $n$ times, $P(X=n)=1$ and $P(X=k)=0$ for all other $k$. You can't use the formula to calculate $P(X=n)$, but for all other $P(X=k)$ the formula still works since $0^{n-k}=0$ if $k\ne n$.

Edit: If you read Hogg and Craig's "Intro to Mathematical Statistics", you will find that they define the binomial distribution with a restriction of $0<p<1$.

Comment: Thanks toronto for your good answer. God blesses you. Is it necessary that in this case the sum of individual probabilities i.e.C(n,x)  + C(n,x+1) + ......+C(n,n) to be 1?

Comment: Individual probabilities are $P(0), P(1), \cdots, P(n)$. The sum of them has to be one.

Comment: My friend told me that it depends upon the value of 'p'. If 'p' is same then the some of P(1) + P(2)+....+P(n) is '1' otherwise not. I can't find any link.